# How would I go about setting up a simple program that registers users data?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I need help setting up a software that would register people's data and put it into a folder. I am not asking "Give me the code" but rather how would you go about doing this? Is this something I should plan step by step? I actually wanted to add a few buttons that would allow the user to add, edit and remove the information.

Also my next question is, is this a simple project or is this difficult to do? If so I will leave this project and switch to something a little bit more easy. If you have recommendations for a simple project, feel free to recommend. I want to make a project that would make me think for myself, but I can't think of anything that would be suitable for me.

**note**

Sorry everyone, I found my answer online after redefining my question. Sorry about this and thanks!

I am looking to create my own projects. I thought this would be easy. I am new to c# and I am still learning.

My progress with c# has been getting much better. I have managed to create a calculator (not amazing) but now I can do it without going online and looking for help. I made another software which would allow me to move a picture in a application (bit hard to explain but it was really easy to make lol)

The only code that I have done so far is adding the "application.exit" function to the exit button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a local database such as Sql Server Express and a .Net MVC  web app you could  set up CRUD (create, read, update, delete) in a few clicks with Entity Framework as your dstabase access framework. You could create your datsbase tables in Sql Server and then create the Mvc Controllers in your mvc app with Entiyy Framewok. I know this is a lot of info to digest for a newbie. Try looking up .net mvc crud online and find something suitable to your needs
 Regards

Comment: Hey Joe, thanks for that. That actually was helpful. I like how you explained things in a simple form and without going too technical. I clearly have a lot to learn (: Thanks a lot!